# How to solve a greatest integer equation for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This is a greatest integer equation. Solve for $x$:
$$
[2x-7]=-3
$$

Comment: $[2x-7]=[2x]-7$

Answer (score 2):

We want to eliminate the floor; see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Equivalences) for some formulas.  We then have $$-3\le 2x-7<-2$$
You can solve this for $x$ to get $$2\le x<2.5$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  First, ignore the greatest integer sign and solve the equation.  You will get a value for $x$.  Then reflect on how much $x$ can increase before the left side gains a full unit.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy friend. 
Firstly you should keep in mind that $x= [x] + \{x\}$ and $0 \leq \{x\}<1$ 
So, $2x-7 - \{2x-7\}=-3$ 
$\implies 2x-4 = \{2x-7\}$ 
$\implies 0 \leq (2x-4)<1$ 
$\implies 2 \leq x < 2.5 \implies x \in [2, 2.5)$
another equivalent method, $[2x -7] = [2x] -7 = -3 \implies [2x] = 4$ 
$\implies 2x - \{2x\} = 4 \implies 2x -4 = \{2x\}$ and you can solve as before. 
In case, in the question $x \in \mathbb{N}$ then you get $x=2$.

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).